# xrandr configuration

Tags: linux, xorg, monitors, xrandr

How to change `xrandr` maximum value?

```
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected 800x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm    800x600        60.0*   
56.0      640x480        60.0     “1024x768_60.00″ (0x78)   63.5MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock   47.8KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock   59.9Hz   
“1024×768″ (0x79)   70.0MHz
        h: width  1024 start 1072 end 1176 total 1328 skew    0 clock   52.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  798           clock   66.1Hz
```

Where the minimum, maximum, and current value of `xrandr` will be store?

If I connect my monitor directly with machine I'm getting  1024x768.

If I connect my monitor via KVM switch the maximum value is 800x600 how to change the max value?

Answer (score 2):

It might be a hardware issue (perhaps, signal quality after KVN switch?).